# How to decide the initial coordinates of centroid while doing clustering (such as in K MEANS)

Tags: clustering, k-means

Suppose we are looking at a scatter chart and from there, by visual inspection, I would like to pick up the coordinates (initial centers) based on the density of the points. Whats are options or tricks known.

Comment: If you want to use K-means, then consider k-means++ centroid initialization

Answer (score 0):

At least a dozen of methods have been proposed.

Too many to list them all here.

The ELKI tool contains a number of them to try out and compare.

See Wikipedia for a few of them, and check relevant literature. There are several studies that compare different methods.